# AppArmor denying a mount operation

Tags: server, apparmor, lxc

How do I convince apparmor to allow this operation?

```
[28763.284171] type=1400 audit(1344273461.387:192): apparmor="DENIED"
operation="mount" info="failed type match" error=-13 parent=7101
profile="lxc-container-with-nesting" name="/" pid=7112 comm="su"
flags="ro, remount, bind"
```

Basically I'm trying to remount the root filesystem read-only (in a mount namespace nested in an LXC container). The setup is a few bind mounts around the place ending with:

```
mount --rbind / /
mount -o remount,ro /
```

I tried every combination of:

```
mount options=(ro, remount, bind) / -> /,
```

I could think of. Adding the rule `audit mount,` shows all the other mounts I do, but not the ones operating on /. The closest I can get is `mount -> /,` which IMHO is too loose. Even `mount / -> /,` denies the remount (while the first bind mount is allowed).

Comment: You may get help here: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/apparmor

Answer (score 2):

As per: http://lwn.net/Articles/281157/

Bind's have the same options as the original, so you can only bind mount a rw copy of /.. unless you remount your entire / to ro.. which I'm guessing you don't want to do.

Needs to be in two steps.

`mount --bind /vital_data /untrusted_container/vital_data`

`mount -o remount,ro /untrusted_container/vital_data`

Comment: Actually, that _is_ exactly what I want to do. All the directories that need to be writable (surprisingly few, btw) are on another filesystem. The only issue is I cannot convince AppArmor to allow this specific operation.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can just disable apparmor

Comment: Yeah, I can either disable AppArmor, or allow mounting anything on /, as I mentioned in the question. Still, that doesn't help me if I actually want to benefit from AppArmor.

Comment: You could try NFS http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=501ABB11.1000100%40ubuntu.com&forum_name=lxc-users